# How to find the summation of the above series upto n terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to find the summation of the above series $$1+\frac{1}{1+2^{2}}+\frac{1}{1+2+3^{2}}+\frac{1}{1+2+3+4^{2}}...$$ upto $n$ terms? I am trying this question by first of all writing the $n^{th}$ term. So far I have guessed the $n^{th}$ term will be $\frac{1}{1+2+3+...+(n-1)+n^{2}}$. But after guessing the $n^{th}$ term, I can't proceed further to find the summation. I have also thought of writing the numerator of the $n^{th}$ term to be $n$ $-$ $(n-1)$. But can't find any good result after this also. So, please help me out.

Comment: To be clear, this is really meant to be $(1+2+3)+(4^2)$ and not $(1+2+3+4)^2$?

Comment: The $n^{\rm th}$ term has denominator $\frac{3n^2-n}2$

Comment: What makes you think this summation will have a nice closed form that is easy to find?  Was this given to you as a practice problem that explicitly asked for a closed form?  Or was it merely asked for you to prove that it converges without caring what the final sum happens to be?  Had you come up with the problem yourself?

Comment: Yes I have came up with the problem myself@JMoravitz. But I am sure that this summation will converge.

Comment: the summation does converge. But you are asking other things.

Comment: Yes you are correct @user170231. But how to solve further?

Comment: According to wolframalpha, it will be $\frac{1}{3}\left(9\log(3)-\sqrt{3}\pi\right)$.  While sums of reciprocals of quadratics do have a known closed form, you are not expected to know it...

Comment: If you want the closed form, I recommend using $\frac1k=\int_0^1x^{k-1}dx$ very carefully.

Comment: I am asking for the formula for the summation upto n terms of the above series@Will Jagy.

Comment: Can you explain me the reason @J.G.?

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question @JMoravitz.

Comment: How so?  Because you didn't read it?  Because it is too advanced for you?  Because you wanted the partial sum rather than the infinite sum?  If because you didn't read, then read it.  If because too advanced, then you should probably not be attempting this problem.  Remember... just because a question can be easy to ask does not mean it will be easy to answer.  If because you wanted the partial sum rather than the infinite, that is easy to remedy by noting $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(k) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty f(k) - \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty f(k)$

Comment: "Can you explain me the reason" See @user170231's answer, on which I've left another comment.

Answer (score 2):

Maple writes this in terms of digamma functions. To do this, compute $$\frac{1}{1+2+3+...+(m-1)+m^{2}} = \frac{2}{m(3m-1)}$$then use partial fractions
$$
\frac{2}{m(3m-1)} = \frac{6}{3m-1} - \frac{2}{m}
$$
and then
$$
1+\frac{1}{1+2^{2}}+\frac{1}{1+2+3^{2}}+\frac{1}{1+2+3+4^{2}}+\dots+
\frac{1}{1+2+3+...+(n-1)+n^{2}} \\
= 
2\psi\left(n+\frac23\right) - 2 \psi(n+1) +3 \ln 3 - \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

More on summations using digamma [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Evaluation_of_sums_of_rational_functions)

The limit as $n \to \infty$ agrees with the comment of JMoravitz.